# the useage of 'of+wh-clause'

Tags: prepositions

For example,

> Juan raised the question **of when the money would be collected**.

Why is there a word 'of' before the when-clause? Can I omit it? How can we use this kind of sentence like a preposition plus wh-clause? Please give me some examples and illustrate it.

Comment: Most native speakers would include a preposition there (if not ***of***, maybe ***about*** or ***regarding, concerning,*** etc.). If you *don't* have a preposition, the utterance could be misinterpreted as telling us ***when Juan raised the question***, rather than what the actual question he raised was. The likelihood of including a preposition jumps to 100% with near-synonymous *Juan raised the **matter** OF when it would happen.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, the structure is: *[ "the" + noun1 + "of" + noun2 ]*, where *noun1* is a type, and *noun2* is a specific example of that type. Your example has a "wh" noun clause, but it's the same for any noun phrase at all, not just "wh"-clauses.

Here's how this function of "of" is described in [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/of):

> **of** *conjunction*
> **8 a** —used as a function word to indicate a particular example belonging to the class denoted by the preceding noun
> *the city of Rome*

In M-W's example, "city" is the type or "class", and "Rome" is the specific instance of a city. You can say "the city of Rome", or you can say "Rome" without losing any information.

Similarly in your sentence, "*the question*" is the type or "class", and the noun phrase "*when the money would be collected*" is the specific instance of "question". And as with the "city of Rome" example, both the type noun and "of" can be omitted:

> Juan raised* when the money would be collected.

It's worth noting that not all "type" nouns work with this "of" structure. So all these are all correct and natural:

> the **philosophy** of stoicism
> the **religion** of Judaism
> the **topic** of unemployment
> the **issue** of whether to reopen Main Street to car traffic

But all these are either meaningless, or "of" has a different meaning:

> <del>the footballer of Messi</del>
> <del>the car company of Honda</del>
> <del>the drink of beer</del>

I don't know exactly what the rule is for which type-nouns work, but the more abstract the concept the more likely they'll work.

*<sub>Note: The meaning of this version is exactly the same as your original sentence but this phrasing is unnatural because "raised" almost always has some noun phrase like, "the question"/"the issue"/"the topic" etc. after it.</sub>